# CSS and menu not working in iOS devices [WordPress]

Tags: jquery, ios, css, wordpress, wow.js

I have a WordPress site. My site does not work as expected on iOS devices such as Mac, iPad and iPhone. Menus and mouse hovering do not function properly only in iOS devices. When clicking menu navigation, I cannot see the menu items. It seems that the font color is same with the background but when clicking on a menu item area, the link works. In addition, it seems that CSS codes related to menus does work in iOS devices only.

I debugged the console errors and found that WOW.js does not work only in Safari.

The following is the screenshot showing console errors in Safari:
[image]

I tried to fix the issue by referring to suggested solutions online including [WOW.js not working properly with Wordpress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528490/wow-js-not-working-properly-with-wordpress) but could not. I also tried to add CSS code related to z-index, but in vain.

**The affected site is http://me2.do/5bP7YQjD.** It's working properly except in iOS devices. Any hints to fix this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have jQuery conflict in WOW.js and others js. please check and add below in your conflicted js file

```
 $.noConflict();
   // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
```

when I've checked console this error found

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: WOW is not defined
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. In this case, are there any resources I can refer to?